# Windows on M.2 cannot be booted to

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I just recently installed Ubuntu on a new 480gb SSD. I had Windows 10 installed previously on an M.2 ssd that is still connected to the PC. I was planning on dual booting and using grub to select windows whenever I wanted to boot to it. After the installation of Ubuntu, my computer will only boot into Ubuntu and Windows is not recognized at all.

I have tried overriding the boot device in the BIOS and changing the boot settings to Legacy only but that hasn't done anything. Even if I select my M.2 hard drive in the boot override section it still boots into Ubuntu.

Comment: If you're still thinking about "legacy" and "changing the boot *drive*" then you haven't yet understood UEFI and its boot process.

Comment: If you have an UEFI system which almost all hardware since Windows 8 released in 2012 is, then you need to have both Windows & Ubuntu installed in same boot mode, both as UEFI on gpt partitioned drives.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi